# Clear interval when condition is true ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, intervals

I'm trying to clear an interval calling the function to check the condition inside an ajax but every 5 seconds I'm still getting the message so the interval is not cleared. What am I doing wrong? I call the function inside the ajax 'update tarea' and I send the interval name and the checked condition but the interval is still running

```
function update_task(update_tarea, interval){
        if(update_tarea === "si"){
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            swal({
            title: "Se ha fijado el próximo recordatorio",
            icon: "success"
            });
        }
    }

//get info profile
    $.ajax({
        url: 'recordatorio.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { iduser: iduser},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.validacion === "ok"){
                var tareas = response['mascotas'];
                var fecha = new Date();
                var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
                var dia = fecha.getDate();
                var año = fecha.getFullYear();
                var fechaHoy = año + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;
                var len = tareas.length;
                for(i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var fechaTarea= tareas[i]['fecha'];
                    var idpetTarea = tareas[i]['idpet'];
                    var idtipo = tareas[i]['idtipo'];
                    var notas = tareas[i]['notas'];
                    var horaTarea = tareas[i]['hora'];
                    var tipotarea = tareas[i]['tipo'];
                    var nombremascota = tareas[i]['petname'];
                    if(fechaHoy === fechaTarea){
                        var interval= idtipo+idpetTarea+"interval";
                         window.interval = setInterval(function () {                            
                            var hH = new Date();
                            var horas = hH.getHours();
                            var minutos = hH.getMinutes();
                            var segundos = hH.getSeconds();
                            var horaHoy = horas + ':' + minutos + ':' + segundos;
                            var string= "Recuerda la tarea <b>''"+tipotarea+"''</b> para tu mascota <b>"+nombremascota+"</b></br>Notas:"+notas;
                            if(horaHoy === horaTarea || horaHoy > horaTarea){
                                swal({
                                    title: "Recordatorio",
                                    text: "Recuerda la tarea <b>''"+tipotarea+"''</b> para tu mascota <b>"+nombremascota+"</b></br><b>Notas</b>:"+notas,
                                    html: true,
                                    icon: "info"
                                });
                                //update tarea
                                window.update_tarea;
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'updatetarea.php',
                                    type: 'post',
                                    data: { idpetTarea: idpetTarea, idtipo: idtipo },
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    async : false,
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        if(response === "ok"){                                      
                                        update_tarea= "si";
                                        update_task(update_tarea, interval);                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            }, 5000); //end interval 

                        }
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting the value of `interval` in your callback function to the console. I think you'll see the same value each time.

Since you're setting the interval in a loop, you're getting multiple intervals but you only have a pointer to one of them. Each time you set the callback function and passing it interval, it's passing the same interval. Try using bind() if that's the case.